# JSON serialization WP7

Tags: .net, silverlight, json, windows-phone-7

HI,

How can I serialize an image using JSON and send it to WCF?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) project.

**edit** I didn't see the image part until after posting. You'll likely want to convert the image to [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) as you would if you were to store it in XML.